# Array-based query parameters

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember (2.14.2) array-based query param set up in my controller & route:

```
// controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['color'],
  color: [],
  actions: {
    setColor(color){
      this.set('color', [parseInt(color.id)])
    }
  }
});
```

and:

```
// route
import Ember from 'ember';

const {Route} = Ember;

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    color: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findAll('color', params);
  }
});
```

and:

```
{{!-- template --}}
<ul>
  {{#each color as |qp|}}
    <li>qp: {{qp}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<ul>
  {{#each model as |model|}}
    <li {{action "setColor" s}}>obj: {{model.id}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I'm noticing, that when I first click an element and replace the query param array, the URL correcetly changes to:

```
?color=%5B1%5D (i.e. ?color=[1])
```

If I manually reload the page, or if I visit the page with this query parameter enabled, Ember replaces/decodes the query parameter to:

```
?color="%5B3%5D" (i.e. ?color="[1]")
```

If I refresh the page again:

```
?color="%5C"%5B3%5D%5C"" (i.e. ?color="\"[3]\"")
```

So it would appear that while Ember is encoding the URLs correctly, it's not decoding incoming query parameters correctly and it interpreting them as strings as opposed to arrays?

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen when you are using a plain query param as opposed to a `refreshModel` query param

Comment: For anyone who comes across this issue, the problem for me was that I was performing a `transitionTo` within the `redirect` route hook for the parent route of this problematic route. For whatever reason this was causing this strange issue. Although this fixes the problem, it doesn't explain it so I'm leaving this open

Comment: There is a long lasting discussion about this issue with a few workarounds https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14174

Comment: For anyone coming across this question, I've run into this issue again with Ember 3.1.0 so this is still an ongoing problem

Comment: Still an issue as of Ember 3.5.1